# DeleteCases does not work with EvenQ? While `Select` works fine

Tags: filtering, conditional

```
EvenQ[FromDigits /@ Tuples[{2, 3, 5, 7}, 5]]
```

Works fine. But

```
DeleteCases[FromDigits /@ Tuples[{2, 3, 5, 7}, 5], EvenQ]
DeleteCases[FromDigits /@ Tuples[{2, 3, 5, 7}, 5], _EvenQ]
```

does not seem to be deleting any `Even` numbers as expected?

What am I doing wrong?

In comparison,

```
Select[FromDigits /@ Tuples[{2, 3, 5, 7}, 5], OddQ]
```

Works perfectly fine!!

MMA: 11.3 X64 (Win)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the selection criterion, `Select` uses a (pure) function, while `*Cases` uses a pattern. Code below works.

```
DeleteCases[FromDigits /@ Tuples[{2, 3, 5, 7}, 5], _?EvenQ]
```

Comment: I cannot believe it's such a simple tweak!! The examples in the documentation is not any more useful than your answer! THANKS!

Comment: @Chen: the thing to remember is that the second argument of `Cases[]`/`DeleteCases[]` is always a *pattern*, while for `Select[]`, the second argument is an expression test. So, `Cases[(* stuff *), EvenQ]` actually means "take everything that matches the symbol `EvenQ`", while `Cases[(* stuff *), _?EvenQ]` (and `Cases[(* stuff *), n_ /; EvenQ[n]]` as well) read as "take everything that gives `True` when `EvenQ[]` is applied", which was what was wanted.

Comment: You can see the difference by evaluating `{Cases[{8, EvenQ}, EvenQ], Cases[{8, EvenQ}, _?EvenQ]}`.

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less good point

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Thx, but my answer is far from being comparable with _Mathematica_'s extensive documentation. I had been thinking of a Chinese idiom suitable to describe the situation and finally I found it: "万事俱备，只欠东风". :)

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ HAHAHAHAHA! Now I am not sure how to respond to this. I have no idea what you are trying to say but I am pretty sure the Chinese idiom is not appropriately used here ...

Comment: @ChenStatsYu My "东风"=`?` here.

Comment: Oh in this case, yes!